# Find a lower bound on $(\boldsymbol{x}^\textrm{T}\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{y})^2-(\boldsymbol{x}^\textrm{T}\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x})^2$

Tags: matrices, inequality

I recently came across of trying to find a lower bound on the following term:
\begin{equation}
\min_{\boldsymbol{x}}\,(\boldsymbol{x}^\textrm{T}\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{y})^2-(\boldsymbol{x}^\textrm{T}\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x})^2
\end{equation}
where $\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ have unit norms, $\boldsymbol{y}$ is fixed (known), and $\boldsymbol{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a symmetric matrix. I am not sure how to approach the problem due to the first term $(\boldsymbol{x}^\textrm{T}\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{y})^2$. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue with largest absolute value and $y$ be any vector orthogonal to $x$

Comment: Largest in absolute value, I think: $A$ might have eigenvalues $10$ and $-100$, say, and $x$ should belong to $-100$ rather than $10$.

Comment: Sorry, I just re-edited the question. $\boldsymbol{y}$ is actually fixed here.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer! Also, for a more general question, is there a way to find a bound on $\min_{\boldsymbol{x}}\boldsymbol{x}^\textrm{T}\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{y}$